# C pipes write/read priority

Tags: c, pipe, fork

I am trying to understand pipes and the use of fork in C. Below is an example of a code that calls `fork()` and then:

- Child process: Reads the `pipe` and prints the content to console.
- Parent process: Writes in the `pipe` "hello world".

  ```
  int main(void)
  {
  pid_t pid;
  int mypipe[2];

  /* Create the pipe. */
  if (pipe(mypipe))
  {
      fprintf(stderr, "Pipe failed.\n");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  /* Create the child process. */
  pid = fork();
  if (pid == (pid_t)0)
  {
      /* This is the child process.
      Close other end first. */
      close(mypipe[1]);
      read_from_pipe(mypipe[0]);//read pipe and print the result to console
      return EXIT_SUCCESS;
  }
  else if (pid < (pid_t)0)
  {
      /* The fork failed. */
      fprintf(stderr, "Fork failed.\n");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  else
  {
      /* This is the parent process.
      Close other end first. */
      close(mypipe[0]);
      write_to_pipe(mypipe[1]);//write "hello world" to the pipe
      return EXIT_SUCCESS;
  }
  }
  ```

My understanding is that we use `pipes`, which are treated as files, so that the child process and the parent process can communicate. (Is this correct ?) Now, since the pipe is being used from both the parent and the child, will the child read an empty `pipe` ? Or will the `pipe` be "Hello world" ? And why ? My guess would be that it is random, since the child and parent process run simultaneously. Is this true ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `man 7 pipe`, "If a process attempts to read from an empty pipe, then read(2) will block until data is available.".

So if the `read` occurs before the `write`, it will wait until the `write` is done.

Reciprocally, if the `read` occurs after the `write`, it's obvious it will return the message.

And at least one of these cases must be true, because, still according to `man 7 pipe`, "POSIX.1-2001 says that write(2)s of less than PIPE_BUF bytes must be atomic", and `PIPE_BUF` is usually large enough to hold much more than "Hello World".

So the `read` will return "Hello world".

Comment: Then the read will return (at most, depending on the buffer size) what is in the pipe, and will not be waiting for more.

Comment: How do you know that `read` will happen before `write`. Parent and child process execute simultaneously correct ? So, wouldn't the `read` result be random ?

Comment: @Shiro: the order is (more or less) random, but if the read happens first, it will block (wait) until after the write, so it doesn't really matter.  The read won't complete until after there is some data in the pipe, and if the write is atomic (a single `write` call of less than `PIPE_BUF` byes), then it will get all the bytes after the `write` completes.

Comment: So, you are saying that  it will randomly return either the "DefaultString" or "DefaultString Hello World" ? randomly ?

Comment: If `read` happen after `write`, it's obvious that it will read everything that is written. If both happen simultaneously, still according to `man 7 pipe`, "POSIX.1-2001 says that write(2)s of less than PIPE_BUF bytes must be atomic". `PIPE_BUF` is usually large enough to contain "Hello world". I'm updating my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Excuse me, what is this "DefaultString"?

Comment: the starting value of pipe, since you said that if its empty, "read" waits for "write" to happen, so i changed it to "DefaultString" so that this doesn't happen (look at my first comment)

Comment: @Shiro:  the starting value for the pipe is empty -- if you want something in it, you need to `write` to it.  If you have multiple `write`s then they won't be atomic, so you might read one or both, depending on the ordering of things.

Comment: @Shiro: Can you edit your question to reflect the new and complete situation, so we can understand exactly in what situation you are?

Comment: I know that the starting value is empty, so I will `write`" DefaultString" in it before fork is called. My question is very simple. I am asking if `read` can happen after `write`, and the opposite,  (if `write` can happen after `read`) in any scenario (with pipe being empty or having a starting value). So that I would get  "DefaultString" in the first case, or "DefaultString Hello world" in the second case . I am trying to understand how things work. This example code is only for demonstration. So please don't just answer the question just for the case that the pipe is empty.

Comment: Yes, both can happen, as @ChrisDodd explained in his comment.